# Which is best to use AngularJS or Twig with Symfony2

Tags: angularjs, symfony, web, seo, google-search

I just need to build a website using Symfony2 but that website need to be pretty much SEO friendly. But as i heard AngularJS + Symfony in not much SEO frindly than TWIG + Symfony. If it is not true what are the things that i can used to my AngularJS + Symfony website to be more SEO friendly.

Comment: Have you already tried something? Have you got an example?

Comment: I think you are missunderstanding the technologies... Twig is part of Symfony components, so regarding to your answers is the same symfony or twig. The problem with SEO is with Angular and the way it exposes the urls, there are many solutions for that but if you have much concern on SEO, maybe you should avoid using angular

Comment: Yes i know that is a part of Symfony what i asked was rather than using Symfony in built Forntend development package 'Twig', is it better to use 'AngulerJS'  with Symfony backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perfectly use AngularJS in Twig templates, with Symfony2 server.
AngularJS is not just a template engine, but Twig yes, with particular file extension due to server side. Angular can be used in all templates engines containing HTML.

Some AngularJS functionalities cannot be associated to Symfony2/Twig, or with difficulties, but you can easily build your application and do your markup in one/many twig templates, and call them using one or many routes.